# Using Custom Formula in Conditional Formatting to highlight cells containing string from comma-delimited list in a single cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to write a custom formula for conditional formatting in a Google Sheet where, if a cell in Column A contains a word from a comma deliminated list in cell C1, it will highlight.

The closest I have gotten was this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--isnumber(search(split($C$1, ",", true, true), A:A)))=counta(split($C$1, ",", true, true))
```

Which returned "True" but I cannot quite figure out how to adapt to the conditional formatting syntax.

I have also tried this, but the query syntax does not like the "," in there, and escape characters don't seem to work.

```
QUERY(Sheet1!A:A, "SELECT A WHERE split($C$1, ",", true, true) ")
```

[Here's the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s10Q5pz-zTQmwgA9KzFAqOkJM2KsNX2LiRafA6lmNGo/edit#gid=0). Basically, I want the cells in column A containing "tree" or "car" or "cat" to highlight in green.

Answer (score 1):

as you say: highlight cells containing string from comma-delimited list in a single cell,

let try:

```
=COUNTIF($C$1,"*" &A2&"*")*(A2<>"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SUBSTITUTE(C$1:C, ",", "|"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(C1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SUBSTITUTE(A$1:A, ",", "|"))))
```

[image: 0]